# "I have every confidence...." -having trouble understanding the countable 'confidence' here

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning, word-usage

An example from [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vindicate#vindicate__4)

> I have ***every confidence*** that this decision will be fully vindicated.

Why is it 'every confidence?'. I dug further checking whether 'confidence' is 'countable'. And I found this on [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/confidence?q=CONFIDENCE)

> [countable] (formal) a secret that you tell somebody

The examples follow:

> The girls exchanged confidences. 
>  I could never forgive Mike for betraying a confidence.

But then, does the first example mean 'secret'? I'm confused.

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/using-every-each-all-the-as-modifier-of-uncountable-nouns (Have a look at Kiam's answer, hmm, curious)

Comment: No, the first example maps to the first definition of _confidence_, that is: "the feeling that you can trust, believe in and **be sure about** the abilities or good qualities of somebody/something." So, _I have **every confidence** that this decision will be vindicated_ means, _I am **quite sure** that this decision will be vindicated_.

Comment: The phrase "every confidence" is rather formulaic; formulas often preserve obsolete or archaic meanings. This ngram shows that the phrase had its heyday around 1900. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(have+every+confidence)&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28have%20every%20confidence%29%3B%2Cc0

Comment: See OED #5, 'an object or ground of trust; that which gives confidence, boldness, or security'.

Comment: @J.R. If it's a normal use, is it countable? I have confidence in doing this work.

Comment: @Maulik - If I was ready to answer that countable-or-not question, I would have left an answer instead of a comment :^) By the way, I think I'd be more inclined to say, _"I have confidence in my work,"_ or, _"I am confident about doing this work,"_ before I'd say,  _"I have confidence in doing this work,"_ but that depends on what you're trying to say. Does doing the work give you greater confidence? Or are you confident in your ability to do the work?

Answer (score 1):

It's ***confidence*** = [trust, belief, faith](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/confidence) (uncountable abstract mass noun) in OP's OALD citation, not the count noun *secret, private communication* sense as subsequently quoted.

The *every confidence* usage is something of an oddity. Note [this from an 1869 grammar book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7YIVAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA231&dq=%22every%20confidence%22%20grammar&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2qgSVcvlCqae7gb_xIGYBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22every%20confidence%22%20grammar&f=false)...

> We should not say *We have **every confidence** in him*, because *confidence* is an abstract noun, and does not mean one of a class of objects. The expression should be *I have **all confidence** in him*.

But as every learner should be aware, native speakers don't always respect the "logical" pronouncements of grammarians, and that one has always been largely ignored. More recent "descriptive" grammarians now define the usage as...

> Typical uses of **every** ([Pocket Fowler's Modern English Usage, 2nd Ed., 2008](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7YIVAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA231&dq=%22every%20confidence%22%20grammar&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2qgSVcvlCqae7gb_xIGYBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22every%20confidence%22%20grammar&f=false))
>    ...
>    **2** - with *some* abstract uncountable nouns referring to a feeling or attitude: *[italics mine]*
>    *We have **every sympathy** for their case*
>    *I have **every confidence** in you*

Almost exactly the same description of this "valid" usage appears in [Harrap's essential English Dictionary, 1996](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=r20pIBUVsHcC&pg=PA319&dq=%22every%20confidence%22%20countable&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZKkSVbfpCYPD7gbW2oGAAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22every%20confidence%22%20countable&f=false), which specifically targets the needs of *Indians* learning English.

It's purely my own opinion, but personally I feel this is something of a "post hoc rationalisation" for usages which might really be better described as "idiomatic, fixed expressions". It's also worth noting that [the ***confidence*** version](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20every%20confidence%2Chave%20great%20confidence&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20every%20confidence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20great%20confidence%3B%2Cc0) has held up far more than [the ***sympathy*** version](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20every%20sympathy%2Chave%20great%20sympathy&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20every%20sympathy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20great%20sympathy%3B%2Cc0), which I feel reflects the fact that *all* such usages are tending to fall into disuse (or at least, they're perceived by native speakers as being somewhat "quirky, old-fashioned, formal").

---

My advice to learners would be to accept...

> *have **every** ["**feeling/attitude" abstract noun**] in/for/to [the target of that feeling]*

...as "valid", but to avoid extending the usage. There's no obvious way of identifying which abstract nouns *everyone* is happy with *(confidence, success),* as opposed to more "marginal" versions *(sympathy, faith),* and completely unacceptable forms (such as ∗*I have **every love** for her*).

In practice I imagine that if they think about it at all, most native speakers perceive ***every*** in such contexts more as an "intensifier" *(I have **complete/absolute/total** confidence in him),* rather than a "quantifier" *(I have **every/all/many** reason/s to trust him)*.